# How do I load multiple Excel files (containing multiple sheets) into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code that I currently have, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to change each of the "with ... as xls" to something else such as "with ... as xls1", "with ... as xls2", "with ... as xls3", etc.?

```
def load_ticket_():
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

with pd.ExcelFile('AnnArbor-TicketViolation2015.xls') as xls:
    columns = ['Ticket #', 'Badge', 'Issue Date', 'IssueTime', 'Plate', 'State', 'Make', '', 'Violation', 'Description', 'Location', 'Meter', 'Fine', 'Penalty']
    df2015_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1', skiprows=0, header=1)
    df2015_1.columns = columns
    df2015_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2', skiprows=0)
    df2015_3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet3', skiprows=0, skipfooter=1)
    sheets2015 = [df2015_1, df2015_2, df2015_3]
    df2015 = pd.concat(sheets2015)
    
with pd.ExcelFile('AnnArbor-TicketViolation2016.xls') as xls:
    columns = ['Ticket #', 'Badge', 'Issue Date', 'IssueTime', 'Plate', 'State', 'Make', '', 'Violation', 'Description', 'Location', 'Meter', 'Fine', 'Penalty']
    df2016_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1', skiprows=0, header=1)
    df2016_1.columns = columns
    df2016_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2', skiprows=0)
    df2016_3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet3', skiprows=0, skipfooter=1)
    sheets2016 = [df2016_1, df2016_2, df2016_3]
    df2016 = pd.concat(sheets2016)
    
with pd.ExcelFile('AnnArbor-TicketViolation2017.xls') as xls:
    columns = ['Ticket #', 'Badge', 'Issue Date', 'IssueTime', 'Plate', 'State', 'Make', '', 'Violation', 'Description', 'Location', 'Meter', 'Fine', 'Penalty']
    df2017_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1', skiprows=0, header=1)
    df2017_1.columns = columns
    df2017_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2', skiprows=0)
    df2017_3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet3', skiprows=0, skipfooter=1)
    sheets2017 = [df2017_1, df2017_2, df2017_3]
    df2017 = pd.concat(sheets2017)
    
with pd.ExcelFile('AnnArbor-TicketViolation2018.xls') as xls:
    columns = ['Ticket #', 'Badge', 'Issue Date', 'IssueTime', 'Plate', 'State', 'Make', '', 'Violation', 'Description', 'Location', 'Meter', 'Fine', 'Penalty']
    df2018_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1', skiprows=0, header=1)
    df2018_1.columns = columns
    df2018_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2', skiprows=0)
    df2018_3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet3', skiprows=0, skipfooter=1)
    sheets2018 = [df2018_1, df2018_2, df2018_3]
    df2018 = pd.concat(sheets2018)
    
with pd.ExcelFile('AnnArbor-TicketViolation2019.xls') as xls:
    columns = ['Ticket #', 'Badge', 'Issue Date', 'IssueTime', 'Plate', 'State', 'Make', '', 'Violation', 'Description', 'Location', 'Meter', 'Fine', 'Penalty']
    df2019_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1', skiprows=0, header=1)
    df2019_1.columns = columns
    df2019_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2', skiprows=0)
    df2019_3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet3', skiprows=0, skipfooter=1)
    sheets2019 = [df2019_1, df2019_2, df2019_3]
    df2019 = pd.concat(sheets2019)

with pd.ExcelFile('AnnArbor-TicketViolation-jan2020.xls') as xls:
    df2020 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1', skiprows=0, header=1)
    df2020.columns = columns
```

**Below is used to test my code:**

### import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
df_1_test = load_ticket_data()
assert isinstance(df_1_test, pd.DataFrame), "Q1: What your function returns must be pd.DataFrame."
assert len(df_1_test) == 811439, "Q1: There should be 811439 rows in the dataframe."
assert len(df_1_test.columns) == 14, "Q1: There should be 14 columns in the dataframe."

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_88/3174118782.py in <cell line: 7>()
5
6 df_1_test = load_ticket_data()
----> 7 assert isinstance(df_1_test, pd.DataFrame), "Q1: What your function returns must be pd.DataFrame."
8 assert len(df_1_test) == 811439, "Q1: There should be 811439 rows in the dataframe."
9 assert len(df_1_test.columns) == 14, "Q1: There should be 14 columns in the dataframe."

AssertionError: Q1: What your function returns must be pd.DataFrame.

Comment: are you getting an error? Why didnt you use a function instead of rewriting the same code many times?

Comment: Typically `pd.read_excel` accepts the path directly, you don't need the context manager

Comment: I'm new to Python programming (and programming in general) so I'm not sure why I didn't use a function instead of rewriting the same code. This is the only way I (somewhat) know how to go about it. How would I go about using a function to shorten my code instead of having to rewrite it all? Since these are all different files that I'm loading into a df (there's a total of 6 files with multiple sheets in each file), would a function be able to work?

Comment: There's no reason to change `xls` to `xls1`, `xls2`, `xls3`. What is the problem when you run your code?

Comment: @Zorgoth I have edited the code above and added the error message that I'm receiving when I run the code.

Comment: Have you actually defined a function? It looks like what you have is a script, and you are passing this to a verification tool that requires a function? EDIT : never mind, i didn't see the def on top. Imports usually come at the beginning of a file rather than inside a function.

But also, does your function return anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to loop the folder with files and load each sheet into data frame, later load all dataframes into the dictionary.
example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def load_ticket_():
    column_names = ['Ticket #', 'Badge', 'Issue Date', 'IssueTime', 'Plate',
                    'State', 'Make', '', 'Violation', 'Description', 'Location', 'Meter', 'Fine', 'Penalty']
    my_files = os.listdir() # my_files = os.listdir(path)
    excel_fnames = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.xlsx'), my_files))
    df_dict = {} # empty dictionary for dataframes
    for file in excel_fnames:
        print(f"excel file: '{file}' is loaded")
        if file != "AnnArbor-TicketViolation-jan2020.xls":
            # read all sheets in one file and name the columns
            sheets_to_df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, names=column_names)
            # append each sheet table to the dataframe per file
            df_dict[file[-9:-5]] = pd.concat(sheets_to_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            df_dict[file[-9:-5]] = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="Sheet1", names=column_names)
    # renaming keys of dictionary to match original code
    df_dict = {f'df{k}': v for k, v in df_dict.items()}
    return df_dict

# calling function to load all dataframes to dictionary
final_dict_of_dfs = load_ticket_()

# show all df names stored in the dictionary
print(final_dict_of_dfs.keys())
# print specific df
print(final_dict_of_dfs['df2017'])
# assign new df from the item in the dictionary
df_2017 = final_dict_of_dfs["df2017"]
# or concat all dfs into one
master_df = pd.concat(final_dict_of_dfs.values(), ignore_index=True)
print(master_df)
```